# i am new to latex. Solve this problem. i dont get big brace

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
g(f,t) =
\begin {cases}
%\begin{align}
       b^Nt^N^-^1e^2^\pi^b^t cos(2\pi ft), & t\geq 0;
      \\
      & 0 & otherwise;
            %\end{align}
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: you should edit your previous question. Please, consider comments below first (original) question. Provide sketch of your equation, this is to erroneous (`b^Nt^N^-^1e^2^\pi^b^t`) that we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You get, instead, tons of error messages. Please, spend some time on a manual: you'll be rewarded.

1. What has to be set as exponent should go in braces: `b^{N}t^{N-1}e^{2\pi bt}`
2. `\cos` should be used instead of `cos`
3. `\text{otherwise}` because it's text
4. Just one `&` per row

The correct code:

```
\begin{equation}
g(f,t) =
\begin {cases}
  b^{N}t^{N-1}e^{2\pi bt} \cos(2\pi ft), & t\geq 0;
  \\
  0 & \text{otherwise};
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```